# How do I run Jest Tests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, jestjs

I have following hello World test to my `__tests__` folder:
hello-test.js:

```
describe('hello world', function() {
 it('basic test', function() {
   expect(1).toBe(1);
 });
});
```

My aim is to eventually write tests in es6 and run using a gulp task. I have tried running the above with the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('jest', ['test-compile'], function(done){
  jest.runCLI({
      rootDir : __dirname,
    //scriptPreprocessor : "../node_modules/babel-jest",
    testFileExtensions : ["es6", "js"],
    }, __dirname, function (result) {
        if (result) {
            console.log(result);
        } else {
            console.log('Tests Failed');
        }
        done();
    });
});
```

I have also tried running jest using the globally install jest-cli and cannot get it to work, I also tried using the npm test way as shown on line but no matter which of these I try I just get `Using Jest CLI v0.6.0` in the terminal, no errors no results.

I am very confused as I seem to be doing what all the doc's online say. I am using `Node 4.2.1` if that has any bearing